# Single-line methods in C++

Tags: c++

I program in C# a majority of the time, so I'm always used to using the "=>" operator for single-line methods like this:

```
int AddNums(int a, int b) => return a + b;
```

But as far as I know, the only way to do this in C++ is by using brackets:

```
int AddNums(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

I'd like to be able to use the single-line convention that I'm used to, but I'm not even sure what it's called. Is this even possible in C++?

Comment: Trivial answer: `int AddNums(int a, int b) { return a + b; }`

Comment: C++ does have lambdas, though they're not as succinct as their LINQ / java cousins

Comment: Someone will be along shortly to prove me wrong, but I don't think you can even abuse macros into doing what you want.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members was added to C# in the last decade or so, I think. In that same time C++ has not followed suit.

Comment: Are you really complaining about the difference between `{ ... }` and `=> ...`?

Comment: Definitely can't match with a macro. Can't start an identifier with `=`.

Comment: Please note that the `=>` convention that you seem to like does NOT necessarily produce the most readable code.  Succinctness should not be the primary goal.

Comment: *I'd like to be able to use the single-line convention that I'm used to* -- That's your main mistake, and that is using C# as a model in writing C++ code.  C++ is not C#.  Do not use one language as a model in writing a program in another language.  All that will happen is code that wind up 1) buggy, 2) Inefficient, or 3) will look weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: Good brain teaser, but whatever you could come up with is almost certainly more work than it's worth.

Comment: @john I'm not complaining. I'm simply asking if it's possible.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, I figured that'd be the only alternative. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand.  Is there any advantage to placing everything on one line?  In C++, whitespace is ignored, so you could place every token on a separate line and still have the equivalent function (in emitted code also).

Comment: @Mav I must be missing something. What's stops you using `{ ... }` but placing it all on one line?

Answer (score 4):

Not really.

You could *format* it in a different way

```
auto AddNums(int a, int b) -> int { return a + b; }
```

Or write a lambda

```
auto add_nums = [](int a, int b){ return a + b; }
```

You'd still going to need those braces to delimit the body of the function.

Comment: This is probably going to make me a lot of enemies, but `int AddNums(int x, int y) <% return x + y; %>` doesn't use braces (technically).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ok, nice try ;). I belive that those digraphs are still *technically* (from a preprocessor and compiler point of view) curly brackets.

Comment: Side note: if compiling to a recent enough Standard you can leave out a bit more: `auto AddNums(int a, int b) { return a + b; }`. All you gain is a bit of future proofing because, smurf, `int` is less typing than `auto`.